# HTML - How to float a div tag above a p tag and a h5 tag in html

Tags: html, css

So here is the thing. I'm using HTML.. i already tried to do the absolute and relative thing.. but somehow it doesnt work for me.. or maybe I'm doing it wrong but anyways here is the question..

- The grey background is the body tag
- The white box the one with the red boarder is a div container that is
  floating
- The green boarder holds a h5 tag
- The blue boarders hold a p tag

If you run the below code snippet you can see the black box is where my 'image' will sit. I just need to make the black box be positioned above all the other tags on the right side inside the white box with red border. Please scroll down to see the entire output of the snippet if u cant see the black box I'm talking about.

```css
/*Location*/
#Location {
  width: 37.5%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 24%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#Location>p {
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#Location>h5 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#MapID {
  height: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="Location">
  <h5>Some text Header</h5>
  <p>Some text: </p>
  <p>Some text: </p>
  <p>Some text: </p>
  <p>Some text: </p>
  <p>Some text: </p>
  <p>Some text: </p>
  <p>Some text: </p>
  <div id="MapID"></div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: why not simply put it `above the content` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use position absolute for this, but the parent of "MapID" needs to have `position: relative` for it to work.

In your example I only added `position: relative` to `#Location` then you can use `position: absolute` as you expect.

```css
/*Location*/
#Location {
  position: relative;
  width: 37.5%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 24%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#Location>p {
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

#Location>h5 {
  padding-left: 10px;
  color: cornflowerblue;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

#MapID {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id="Location">
  <h5>Some text Header</h5>
  <p>Some text: </p>
  <p>Some text: </p>
  <p>Some text: </p>
  <p>Some text: </p>
  <p>Some text: </p>
  <p>Some text: </p>
  <p>Some text: </p>
  <div id="MapID"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya that is exactly what i did.. but it doesn't seem to work on my code any ideas y though :/

Comment: If it works in the snippet above, but not in your code it's hard to tell why. Make sure you are not accidentally overriding the `position` value somewhere else in your CSS. Inspect the element in Chrome to see what CSS values are actually used if you are unsure.